# Problemas con view index en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo que hacer un resumen, para eso necesito traer 5 tablas de la base de datos, estoy en summaries controller hice todo los @ de los 5 mas uno de una tabla de intermedio (N a N) pero me sale este error

```
undefined method `each' for #<Room:0x0000000142560a98>
```

se que se debe a que la variable del controlador esta en singular y deberia estar en plural @,  esta en plural pero lo demas igual pero me sale el mismo error estoy codificando la vista y estoy armando lo de @rooms pero sigue dandome el mismo problema.

Controller

```
 before_action :set_reservation, only: [:index]


  def index    
    @reservations = Reservation.all
    @reservation
    @items = ItemReservation.find_by(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
    @rooms = Room.find_by(id: @items.room_id)
    @user = UserReservation.find_by(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
    @other = OtherReservation.find_by(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
    @sight = ObsReservation.find_by(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
  end

  private

  def set_reservation
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
  end

end
```

View

```
<h1>Summaries#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/summaries/index.html.erb</p>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class= "col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        Codigo de Reserva: <%= @reservation.codreserve %> <br/>
        Fecha de creacion: <h3><%= @reservation.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %> </h3>
      </div>
      <div class= "col-sm-12 col-md-4"><br>
        Ckeckin: <h3><%= @reservation.checkin %> </h3>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        Estado: <b><%= @reservation.status %><br/></b>
        Check Out: <h3><%= @reservation.checkout %> </h3>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div clase= "row">
    <div class= "col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <% @rooms.each do |rm|%>
        <%= @rooms.id %>
      <%end%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_by` siempre te va a retornar tan solo una instancia del modelo (el primero en encontrar), sin importar que haya más de un registro cumpliendo tus criterios de búsqueda. Para ejecutar `.each`, necesitas una colección de modelos que pueda ser iterada, por lo tanto deberías usar `.where`.

Guiándome por los nombres de tus variables en plural, supongo que estos deberían estar usando `where`:

```
@items = ItemReservation.where(reservation_id: @reservation.id)
@rooms = Room.where(id: @items.room_id)
```